# a global pointer from a header file is manupulated in a .c file, but its value is NULL when accessed from main function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, static, global-variables

files we are dealing with: **struct.h**, **struct.c**, **main.c**
I compiled and run my program on the site https://www.onlinegdb.com/  with extra compiler flag: `-std=c11`.

small and compilable code that demonstrates my problem:

---

### struct.h

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#define STRUCT_H

struct linkedlist
{
    int data;
    struct linkedlist *next;
};

static struct linkedlist *head = NULL, *end_node = NULL;

void build_linkedlist();
#endif
```

---

### struct.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "struct.h"

void build_linkedlist()
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedlist));
    head->data = 5;
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedlist));
    head->next->data = 12;
    head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedlist));
    head->next->next->data = 34;
    head->next->next->next = NULL;
    end_node = head->next->next;

    printf("from struct.c: head = %p\n\n", head);
}
```

---

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "struct.h"

int main()
{
    build_linkedlist();
    printf("from main.c: head = %p\n", head);
    return 0;
}
```

---

### output

```
from main.c: head = (nil)
from struct.c: head = 0x55c1eca476b0
```

---

### My requirement and the problem:

I want to access members of every node in the linkedlist from the `main` function, but as you can see, the value of `head` pointer when accessed from `main` function is `nil` (I guess that means NULL). Due to this, I'm getting segmentation fault when I try to access its members.

**How to resolve this?**

Comment: `static` means different things depending on the place you put it. In your case, `static` means this variable is visible only in this current C file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header file contains `static` definitions for `head` and `end_node`.  That means each source file that includes them gets its own copy of that variable.  So `head` in main.c is a different variable than `head` in struct.c, and the same for `end_node`.

If you want a variable to be visible in all translation units, you need to *declare* it the header without the `static` keyword:

```
extern struct linkedlist *head, *end_node;
```

And *define* it in exactly one source file:

```
struct linkedlist *head = NULL, *end_node = NULL;
```

Comment: as you said, I declared them "extern"ally in the `struct.h` file (without any initialisation) and **defined** them in the `struct.c` file (with NULL initialisation). But I'm still getting same output; didnt solve my problem.

Comment: @Cinverse Try building the list first, *then* printing in `main`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that,  its now working as required, thanks